# Dataframe groupby and list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following dataframe and I am trying to create the list of all 'values' for a given 'id'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'month': [2, 2, 4, 6],
                   'value': [4, 5, 4, 3],
                   })

print (df)
print ("\n")

print (df.apply(lambda x: list([x['id'], x['month']
                        x['value']]), axis=1),)
```

The expected output is

```
1    [[2,4], [2, 5]]
2    [[4, 4], [6, 3]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `apply` to get new Series object like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'month': [2, 2, 4, 6],
                   'value': [4, 5, 4, 3],
                   })

res = df.groupby('id').apply(
    lambda group: [[group.month[i], group.value[i]] for i in range(len(group))])
```

Output:

```
id
1    [[2, 4], [2, 5]]
2    [[4, 4], [6, 3]]
dtype: object
```

Or you could use same `groupby` + `apply` combination to get similar Dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'month': [2, 2, 4, 6],
                   'value': [4, 5, 4, 3],
                   })

res = df.groupby('id').apply(
    lambda group: pd.DataFrame(
        {'result': [[[group.month[i], group.value[i]] for i in range(len(group))]]}))
res.index = res.index.droplevel(1)
```